# How do I make a 600x600 gif if I possess the individual frames?

Tags: windows, image, gif

So far the best program by far is Ulead GIF Animator, and it does not accept more than 61 frames (I have 139). When I stitch the 61 together I open it in Irfanview and it's very slow and laggy. Actually, it's about a third of the speed when I play the animation in GIF Animator.

Can I get someone's thoughts on this?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Photoshop to build GIFs.  I quite enjoyed working in Photoshop to do this as well.

Per a post from [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/792760) you can do up to 500 frames...

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as the right one, even though I decided to go with Flash, because of quality. And because it answers the original question. Thanks, Mickelback.

Comment: Your welcome, I was just hoping I wasn't too generic in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

GIFs are notorious for low quality especially if you are using images with high dpi.  [Adobe Flash Pro](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash) is excellent for handling a multitude of frames, the ability to  convert images to objects cuts the file size in half but you will still run into performance issues when converting to gif.  You could publish an swf and embed with [SWFObject.](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)